# Induced Morphism on Fibre Product

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a proper $k$-scheme and $k \subset k'$ a field extension. Consider the fibre product \ base change $X' = X \otimes _k k'$.

Let $\mathcal{F} \in Coh(X)$ and $p: X' \to X$ the canonical projection (I think that it is a affine morphism (why ?).

Does and why $p_* (p^* (\mathcal{F})) = \mathcal{F} \otimes _k k'$ hold?

Comment: This is called the *projection formula*, see Hartshorne *Residues and Duality*, Proposition II.5.6 (though their is certainly an easier proof in your very simple case).

Comment: On a basis of affine opens, this is immediate from Hartshorne *Algebraic Geometry*, **Proposition II.5.2(d,e)**.